# jquery on click activate another on click, but the closest one in the mark up

Tags: jquery

This is baking my noodle, any pro ideas/advice would great thanks.

I have my mark-up below...

```
<a href="#" class="launch-fancybox">Preview Image Gallery</a>


<!-- lots of mark up in between -->


<a href="enlarge-1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="thumb-1.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a href="enlarge-2.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="thumb-2.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a href="enlarge-3.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a href="enlarge-4.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="thumb-4.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Then my fancybox jquery...

```
$('.fancybox').on('click', function () {

    var data = $(this).attr('data-rel');

    $('.fancybox[data-rel="' + data + '"]').attr('rel','fancybox-thumb').fancybox({

        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   :  null,
            overlay : {
                opacity : 0.8,
                css : {
                    'background-color' : '#000'
                }
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        },
        closeClick: true

    });

});
```

Now my question is, how can I get my link with the class 'launch-fancybox' to find the very first/closest link with the class 'fancybox' and run the script above.

Basically I want simulate clicking on the first thumbnail. But instead by clicking the 'launch-fancybox' link.

Any ideas or pointers in how I could do this would be awesome.

Thanks

======================================================

I even tried putting my jquery into a function...

```
fancybox = function () {

    var data = $(this).attr('data-rel');

    $('.fancybox[data-rel="' + data + '"]').attr('rel','fancybox-thumb').fancybox({

        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   :  null,
            overlay : {
                opacity : 0.8,
                css : {
                    'background-color' : '#000'
                }
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        },
        closeClick: true

    });

};

$('.fancybox').on('click', fancybox);


$('.launch-fancybox').on('click', function (e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('.fancybox').click();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.launch-fancybox').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.fancybox').click();
});
```

Comment: That is so strange - I can see totally how this would work, and i'm not getting any errors. But nothing happens. I've tried closest as the mark up above is not exact to mine. It's like it just not finding the next .fancybox

Comment: Ahh i changed it to this... `$('.fancyapps[data-rel="thumb"]').first().click();` and used your click method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method should do what you want.

Comment: I ammend the code above in @Reza answer to closest, as my links are further down the page. Though its like it can't find it. Very odd, i'm not getting errors.